# Why Facebook Session state is always close?

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I want to add Facebook login functionality into my app. Please note that:

1. I don't want to use Facebook login button widget.
2. I copy pasted my code that was working correctly last year (from my other project) into my new project.
3. I checked [Session](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Session/) page and I guess I have no problem.

The only difference was `Request.executeMeRequestAsync()` hss changed to `Request.newMeRequest()`. I did this change but seems my session is always close although I could see `Session.setActiveSession(session);` method runs by debug of project. So, have no idea really why `session` is always close in `call()` method.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.

My code:

```
public class FacebookLogin extends FragmentActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = "FacebookLogin";

    private static final List<String> READ_PERMISSIONS =
            Arrays.asList("email", "user_about_me", "user_photos");
    //    private static final List<String> WRITE_PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("");


    private final Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
        {
            if (session.isOpened())
            {
                // make request to the /me API
                Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()
                {
                    // callback after Graph API response with user object
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                    {
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            MyLog.d(TAG, "User name: " + user.getName() + "!, Login successfully :)");
                            MyLog.d(TAG, "User id: " + user.getId());
                            MyLog.d(TAG, "Access token is: " + session.getAccessToken());
                            MyLog.d(TAG, "Application id: " + session.getApplicationId());
                            MyLog.d(TAG, "JSON Object: " + user.getInnerJSONObject());

                            SpStorage.setKeyFacebook(FacebookLogin.this, session.getAccessToken());
                            SpStorage.setFacebookUserId(FacebookLogin.this, user.getId());

                            // erson person = parseJSON(user.getInnerJSONObject().toString());
                            // registerUser();

                            // Close activity
                            FacebookLogin.this.finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
                request.executeAsync();
            }
            else if (state.isClosed()) {
                MyLog.d(TAG, "Facebook session closed");
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Find device hash key (should not be used in production)
//        printHashKey();

        // start Facebook Login
        openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback, READ_PERMISSIONS);
    }

    private static Session openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI,
            Session.StatusCallback callback, List<String> permissions)
    {
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session
                .OpenRequest(activity)
                .setPermissions(permissions)
                .setCallback(callback);
        Session session = new Session.Builder(activity).build();
        if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI)
        {
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForRead(openRequest);
            return session;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

What I get in logcat:
`Facebook session closed`

Comment: Is this your full Fragment class? You don't seem to be overriding the onActivityResult method and passing it on to the session, which is essential for doing login.

Comment: Thanks @MingLi. you are right I forgot to add that method in my activity. Please write your comment as answer then I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the onActivityResult method in your Fragment class and pass it on to the session in order to complete the session transitions.

This needs to happen regardless of whether you're using the UiLifecycleHelper or not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override onActivityResult and pass the values to the facebook SDK.
From Facebook's SDK docs:

> To ensure that the sessions are set up correctly, your fragment must
>   override the fragment lifecycle methods: onCreate(), onResume(),
>   onPause(), onDestroy(), onActivityResult() and onSaveInstanceState()
>   and call the corresponding UiLifecycleHelper methods. For example,
>   calling the onCreate() method in the UiLifecycleHelper object creates
>   the Facebook session and opens it automatically if a cached token is
>   available.

Answer (score 1):

Recently Facebook is using API V2.2 and it has deleted some methods.
recently Before 1 week i have done some for getting user information.
Which may be helping you.

```
public void getProfileData(View button){
         Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
         new Request(
                    activeSession,
                    "me",
                    null,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            /* handle the result */
                                                 try
                                                    {   GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
                                                        JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
                                                        String name23   = jso.getString("name");
                                                        Log.e("Name  response",""+name23);
                                                        name = name23;
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                   }
                                                    catch ( Throwable t )
                                                    {
                                                        t.printStackTrace();
                                                    }
                             String name = response.toString();
                             Log.e("Name  request",""+name);
                        }
                    }
                ).executeAsync();
    }
```